# Add MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio

How can I fix this error I get when I am trying to "Add MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are probably missing a dll reference. I would suggest looking in Dependencies and making sure there is EntityFramework. If not try adding it.

Comment: This is a very common Core issue.  It has nothing to do with controllers or views.  Make sure you are using Net 4.7.2 or newer which fixes targeting Core issue.  Core is a compact version of Net that was developed to work with less memory on Mobile Devices.  So the Core library does not have all the features of the full version of Net.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0

Comment: Now that I've seen it here, the Mysql.Data.EntityframeworkCore package has been discontinued. I think that was it. And now I don't know how to do it.